# Requirements for dispatching in Star Control 2?

Tags: star-control-2

For a while I was able to dispatch a ship to planet surfaces, but currently the game isn't letting me.  What are the requirements for dispatching to the planet surface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 4 requirements to be able to land on the planet surface:

1. It must NOT be a planet covered by Ur-Quan Slave Shield. E.g. you can't land on Earth, or Chmmmr's planet; or Syreen's planet. You won't even be able to scan them.
2. You have to have at least one planetary lander (you start out with one; but it is possible to sell it for 500RU during your stay on Earth Starbase; or have it be destroyed by the hostile environment or hostile life-forms on the planet).

   You can see if you have any landers in 2 ways:

   - At the starbase, when outfitting modules:

     [image]
   - When looking at your ship diagram, any landers you own will be displayed as small squiggles above fuel counter, right below the ship's name:

     [image]
3. You must have crewmembers on your Precursor vessel.

   It's quite possible to have your vessel with zero crew: You either sell them all at the starbase; or transfer 100% of the crewmembers to other ships.

   [image]
4. You must have sufficient fuel for landing.

   - The amount of fuel required for landing depends on the planet
   - It usually varies between 0.2 and 1 fuel units
   - The exact fuel needed will be displayed when you're scanning the planet, **after you hit "DISPATCH"** option in the menu.

     [image]

Comment: As a side note: Having full cargo space does NOT prevent you from landing - though it will prevent your lander from picking up any more minerals

Comment: 5.  You cannot land on a Gas Giant (no surface), or on any living race's homeworld (game prevents you from reaching the exploration menu).

Comment: Also, landing fuel cost is capped at 3.  http://wiki.uqm.stack.nl/Talk:List_of_planets  Some world types tend to be more massive: Super-Dense especially, then Redux and Ultramarine.

Comment: An important (I think) note: If you're generally low on fuel, landing on a few planets might make the difference between getting home and, well, not getting home. And Melnorme fuel is expensive!